# nextflow: use global variable and use .name in another script (create index)

Tags: dsl, nextflow

I have two scripts: `main.nf` and `index_process.nf` Third I am creating without passing variable `dummy_index_process.nf`
I initially create index by passing parameters, however I understood that `params.` can be used under global scope.

When I pass variable I use `.name` on the fasta file. I'm unable to create index using global variable with `.name` at the step of output `{.ann, .etc}`

Please see below three code snippets: 1) main.nf 2) passing fasta to index 3) using global in index

**main.nf**

```
params.outdir_index_temp="./bwa_index_temp"
params.hg38genome ="/Users/username/Downloads/NM.fasta"

include {bwa_index} from './index_process.nf'
include {bwa_index_dummy} from './dummy_index_process.nf'

workflow {
    bwa_index(params.hg38genome)
    bwa_index_dummy()    
}
```

**index_process.nf** (works fine)

```
process bwa_index {

    tag {ref_fasta.name}

    publishDir "$params.outdir_index_temp/", mode:"copy"

    input:
    path ref_fasta

    output:
    tuple val(ref_fasta.name), path("${ref_fasta.name}.{ann,amb,sa,bwt,pac}")

    """
    bwa index "${ref_fasta}"
    """
}
```

**dummy_index_process.nf** (error with output path)

```
process bwa_index_dummy {

    tag {{params.hg38genome}.name}

    publishDir "$params.outdir_index_temp/", mode:"copy"

    output:
    tuple val(params.hg38genome), path("${{params.hg38genome}.name}.{ann,amb,sa,bwt,pac}")

    """
    bwa index "${params.hg38genome}"
    """
}
```

I am struggling at `path("${{params.hg38genome}.name}.{ann,amb,sa,bwt,pac}")` I cannot understand how to use `.name`

Error I get is:

```
ERROR ~ Error executing process > 'bwa_index (null)'

Caused by:
  Missing output file(s) `null.{ann,amb,sa,bwt,pac}` expected by process `bwa_index (null)`

Command executed:

  bwa index "/Users/name/Downloads/NM.fasta"

Command exit status:
  0

Command output:
  (empty)

Command error:
  [bwa_index] Pack FASTA... 0.01 sec
  [bwa_index] Construct BWT for the packed sequence...
  [bwa_index] 0.34 seconds elapse.
  [bwa_index] Update BWT... 0.01 sec
  [bwa_index] Pack forward-only FASTA... 0.01 sec
  [bwa_index] Construct SA from BWT and Occ... 0.11 sec
  [main] Version: 0.7.17-r1188
  [main] CMD: bwa index /Users/name/Downloads/NM.fasta
  [main] Real time: 0.494 sec; CPU: 0.491 sec

Work dir:
  /Users/name/Documents/path/nextflow_scripts/pipeline/work/c1/2916e08cb93e92d175520b9db71976

Tip: you can replicate the issue by changing to the process work dir and entering the command `bash .command.run`

 -- Check '.nextflow.log' file for details
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because `params.hg38genome` is just a regular `java.lang.String` (i.e. a string). It has no
`name` attribute like `file`/`path` (`sun.nio.fs.UnixPath`) objects do. Without an [`input`](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/process.html#inputs) block, Nextflow will not know to stage *any* input files into the process working directory when the job is run. This will mean that there's no guarantee your FASTA file will be available when the job is run. On a shared/local filesystem, you may not notice any issues with an absolute path. But Nextflow pipelines are intended to be portable. If you later tried to run that code in the cloud for example, you'd likely get a *FileNotFound* exception or similar when your tool discovers that the file is missing. With regards to your first piece of code, you might also prefer:

```
process bwa_index {

    tag { ref_fasta.name }

    publishDir params.outdir_index_temp, mode:"copy"

    input:
    path ref_fasta

    output:
    tuple val(ref_fasta.name), path("*.{ann,amb,sa,bwt,pac}")

    """
    bwa index "${ref_fasta}"
    """
}
```

Comment: I am developing pipeline with human genome. Creating index takes ~55 mins. Is there a way in *nextflow* to check and skip if index files are already present?

Comment: @DeathMetal There are a few ways. But if you're just looking to use cached results, you can use the [`-resume`](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/getstarted.html#modify-and-resume) option on the command line.

Comment: Hi @Steve - can you please help me with this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77566271/nextflow-splitcsv-seven-column-file-using-multimap