# nextflow: splitCsv seven column file using multiMap

Tags: pipeline, nextflow

I have a seven columns' CSV file which I'm trying to read and split. The file has sample ID, WES normal R1, WES normal R2, WES tumor R1, WES tumor R2, RNA normal R1, RNA normal R2 FASTQ files.

WES is whole exome sequecing. FASTQ data are raw DNA/RNA files. R1 and R2 are forward, reverse read files respectively.

```
process split_file {

output:stdout

script:

def csv_file=file("../upgraded_split_csv/wes_rna.csv")

Channel.fromPath( csv_file )
        .splitCsv( )
                .multiMap { row ->
                def rna=tuple(file(row[5]), file(row[6]))
            def tumor_reads = tuple( file( row[3]) ,file(row[4]))
            def normal_reads = tuple(file(row[1]),file(row[2]) )
            
            tumor:
                tuple( row[0], tumor_reads )
            normal:
                tuple( row[0], normal_reads )
        }.view()

"""
echo "helo\n"

"""
}

workflow {
split_file()
}
```

I get error as:

> ERROR ~ Error executing process > 'split_file'
>
> Caused by:   No signature of method:
> nextflow.extension.OperatorImpl.view() is applicable for argument
> types: (groovyx.gpars.dataflow.stream.DataflowStreamReadAdapter,
> groovyx.gpars.dataflow.stream.DataflowStreamReadAdapter) values:
> [DataflowStream[?], DataflowStream[?]] Possible solutions:
> view(groovyx.gpars.dataflow.DataflowReadChannel),
> view(groovyx.gpars.dataflow.DataflowReadChannel, groovy.lang.Closure),
> view(groovyx.gpars.dataflow.DataflowReadChannel, java.util.Map),
> view(groovyx.gpars.dataflow.DataflowReadChannel, java.util.Map,
> groovy.lang.Closure), grep(), find() -- Check script 'split_csv.nf' at
> line: 9